# How do you reload XBindkeys in Ubuntu

Tags: xbindkeys

I have tried a number of options to reload xbindkeys after changing the configuration file (my configuration file is located at  ~/.xbindkeysrc).  Nothing seems to work.  The configuration file should be reloading automatically after a change according to the man page.  How can I force a reload of the file?  In Arch Linux it [appears](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Installation) you can use `xbindkeys --poll-rc` to reload the configuration but this is not working for me in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

If xbindkeys is not reloading automatically after a change you can force it to reload the configuration by using the following command:

`killall -HUP xbindkeys`

Comment: What does `-HUP` stand for? neither of these arguments stand in the `man` page...

Comment: @JohannesLemonde `-HUP` is a signal defined in `man 7 signal` - usually it results in the process getting kicked and reloaded, at least for xbindkeys.  Different apps do different things when they receive a `HUP` signal.

Answer (score 1):

> `xbindkeys` reload its configuration file each time it has changed.
>   But if you want to force it reloading its configuration file, you can
>   send a HUP signal:
>
> `killall -HUP xbindkeys`
>
> When `HUP` signal is send to xbindkeys, changes in
>   `$HOME/.xbindkeysrc` takes effect only after moving mouse.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/xbindkeys